# Bat file for compiling unknown number of C files

Tags: batch-file

I have some c files that I want to compile separately and link them together using a bat file. I will compile/link them using gcc.

The problem is that new c files might be added and I want the bat file to compile/link everything without knowing the exact number of files(without modifying the bat file).

Something like :

```
for X=1:number_of_c_files
    gcc -c sourceX.c
```

and then link them together.

All the files 
are named compile_to_cX.c , where X is a value from 1 to the number of c files from the directory.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite trivial.

```
for %%i in ( *.c ) do (
    gcc -c "%%i"
)
```

**ETA**

I don't remember if you can specify *.o to gcc, but I think you can, in which case it would be something like:

```
gcc *.o [options]
```

Another option would be to accumulate the .o file names into an environment variable.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set O_FILES=
for %%i in ( *.o ) do (
    set O_FILES=!O_FILES! %%i
)

gcc %O_FILES% [other options]
```

Really, you should probably use a makefile though.

Comment: What about linking ? I need to do this simultaneously with something like gcc -Xlinker -no-as-needed compile_to_c1.o ... compile_to_c100.o -x none

Comment: It does not work the same way compiling did

Comment: I appreciate your help but none worked for linking. I will try to make a new topic for this question.